# TIBCO BW 5 create custom java function for all projects

Tags: xpath, tibco, tibco-business-works, tibco-designer

I can create a **custom java function** by adding a custom java function activity and loading my class into it.

I would like to create a custom java function for **all my projects** so I don't need to **repeat** the same thing with every project.

Is it possible to do such thing ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best approach to do this is to include your custom function in a DTL and use the DTL across your projects.

Comment: Please explain what is DTL?

Comment: A DTL is a BW 5.X Design Time Library, this is a set of BW resources (processes, shared resources, and etc) that are packaged together and cab be shared between projects.
See Chapter 19 Sharing Common Resources with Other Projects in Process Design Guide available on http://docs.tibco.com for details.

Comment: Actually that's what i did as an alternative ! I thought there's another way of doing such thing, Thank you @EmmanuelM